# shell get opt is catputre $1 as argument

Tags: bash, shell

```
FILE_LIST=$1
MOVE=0
while getopts "m" OPT; do
 case $OPT in
          m) MOVE=1 ;;
          M) MOVE=1 ;;
          *) echo "Invalid parameter." >&2; exit 1 ;;
 esac
done

echo $MOVE

echo $FILE_LIST
```

I will pass optional argument ( -m/-M) and file list .

```
test.sh -m a.txt
```

its display `1 -m ,` but i am looking for `1 a.txt`

```
Supost if test.sh a.xt
```

it should be diplsay `0  and a.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [`shift`](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_07.html) the arguments.

```
MOVE=0
while getopts "mM" OPT; do
 case $OPT in
          M|m) MOVE=1
               shift;;
          *) echo "Invalid parameter." >&2; exit 1 ;;
 esac
done

echo $MOVE
FILE_LIST=$1
echo $FILE_LIST
```

You can also combine `m` and `M` into one case.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you want the syntax for running the script to be something like:

```
./scriptname [-mM] firstfile [secondfile ...]
```

If this is correct, none of the other answers quite work; here's how I'd do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Parse command options
MOVE=0
while getopts "mM" OPT; do
    case "$OPT" in
        m|M) MOVE=1 ;;
        *) echo "Invalid option." >&2; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done
shift $(( OPTIND-1 )) # Remove options from the argument list

# Parse command arguments
if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "No files specified." >&2
    exit 1
fi
FILE_LIST=( "$@" ) # Use an array in case of spaces in filenames

# Some examples of things to do with the results:

# Work with the specified files individually:
for FILE in "${FILE_LIST[@]}"; do
    chmod g+w "$FILE"
done

# Work with the specified files as a group:
if (( MOVE == 1 )); then
    mv "${FILE_LIST[@]}" "$DEST_DIR"
else
    cp "${FILE_LIST[@]}" "$DEST_DIR"
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

I do not exactly know what you want but Here are some code examples:
First example assumes that the filelist is given always after the -m option

```
while getopts "m:" OPT
do
  case $OPT in
    m)
       echo "option m"
       FILE_LIST = $OPTARG
       ;;
    *) 
       echo "error"
       ;;
  esac
done

echo $FILE_LIST
```

Or a different approach with a filelist not related to the -m option

```
while getopts "m:" OPT
do
  case $OPT in
    m)
       echo "option m"
       MOVE = 1
       ;;
    *) 
       echo "error"
       ;;
  esac
done

shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
FILE_LIST = $1
echo $FILE_LIST
```

Hope this suits your needs

Comment: -1 This doesn't print out what the OP wants. Also has incorrect syntaxt. You can't have spaces before/after the `=` when assigning variables.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `$OPTARG` value for this. Notice `m:`. The colon specifies that there are arguments passed to `-m`

```
#!/bin/bash
MOVE=0
while getopts "m:M:" OPT; do
 case $OPT in
        m|M) MOVE=1
           FILE_LIST="$FILE_LIST $OPTARG"
           ;;
        *) echo "Invalid parameter." >&2; exit 1 ;;
 esac
done
shift $(( OPTIND-1 ))

[[ $MOVE != 1 ]] && FILE_LIST=$1

echo $MOVE
echo $FILE_LIST
```

Comment: In case the arguments have spaces, use an array to capture the file list: `FILE_LIST+=( "$OPTARG" )`, and then `echo "${FILE_LIST[@]}"`

Comment: -1 This doesn't work correctly if I run `script.sh a.txt`. It should print `0 a.txt`.

Comment: @dogbane Fixed. I didn't get what Supost meant first.